Why doesn't Singapore stamp passports?
I know this is a stupid question, but I'm interested in the purpose behind this practice. I know some countries rely on such developed countries as Singapore to prove your visa. For example, my US/UK/EU visas made it easy for me to enter almost any country even when my friends get rejected.

For clarification, do you mean visas or entry/exit stamps?

@jcaron both of them

It should be useful for them. Singapore has a very different size (geographically) as the US/EU (and magnitude less entry points): upgrade of systems and also check at central point is much quick and easier.

Israeli customs will often not stamp passports as a courtesy to people who may get into trouble back home. Bangladeshi passports forbid travel to Israel, but there is no ban in Israel that forbids these people from visiting, so they don't get stamped

No one really hates singapore enough that a hypothetical exit/entry stamp would be an issue. Also if memory serves, we have two functioning civil airports, 2 land checkpoints, and about half a dozen or so sea checkpoints (though we'd likely be losing a few as the port consolidates to tuas from the 3-4 previous terminals we had), and a integrated system that manages all this.


I know some countries rely on such developed countries as Singapore to prove your visa.

The utility of a visa and entry/exit record for Singapore in for Singaporean interests alone. The utility for the travellers to prove their travel record to other countries are not of their concern.
For Singapore, an electronic system for visa, entry/exit record etc. are beneficial since it is counterfeit-proof, more secure (e.g. to identify people with different passports or block someone from getting on a plane), and more efficient to process (e.g. e-gates).
Physical stamping is being phased out in many countries.
Australia and New Zealand have been issuing fully digital visa for many years and allow the use of e-Gates for many nationalities without physical entry/exit stamps.
U.S. and Canada no longer routinely stamp passports and I-94 has been electronic for most travellers for a while.
The UK will be phasing out physical visa and residence permit next year and implement a fully digitalised system.
Schengen countries have wanted to phase out physical stamps for 15+ years an this is delayed due to legal and technical difficulties. The EU has already passed the necessary regulations and the electronic entry/exit system should be (unless delayed again...) implemented this year. The EU also aims for visa digitalisation by 2028 (but if EES and ETIAS are of any indication it won't be done until 2035...).
It will likely pose problems for e.g. the implementation of transit or other visa exemptions granted to holders of these visas in other countries, but again, this is not really a concern for the countries delivering these visas, but the countries that give these beneficial treatments.

It's worth noting that airlines can query a country's ETA system for the existence/validity of an ETA for a given passenger. They routinely use it to check that one has an ETA to travel to that country. No idea if they could/would do that to check the existence of an ETA for country A when travelling to country B.

There's also the issue of certain countries' being more, ah... suspicious of someone with stamps from their avowed enemy. E.g. Israel gives the option of stamping or not stamping a passport in case a traveler may wish to visit other ME countries, many of which may harass or delay entry if one has an Israeli stamp in their passport.

@JedSchaaf some countries even go so far as to issue a second passport for that reason as well.

The EU visa digitalisation plan only covers Schenge (short-stay) visas, it's not quite comparable to the Australian scheme and physical visas will remain a thing for Schengen countries even after that plan comes to fruition.

@Relaxed The EU plan (2023/2667) also allows the digitalisation of national visas, though not residence permits.

In 2667? Maybe ;) I have not seen any reference to that anywhere but if the EU goes to the trouble of building an infrastructure, it makes sense they would “allow” member states to piggy back on it but I am confident it won't happen on the same timeframe everywhere and physical visas will remain a thing in 2030 and beyond.

@Relaxed See citation 45 and art. 4 of https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2023/2667/oj; I agree it probably won't be on schedule.

@Relaxed haha, yeah, 2667 is about when I'm estimating that the EU electronic travel authorization and also the U.S. REAL ID requirements will go into effect. :) There are people who have non-REAL ID-compliant driver's licenses in the U.S. now who were born after the REAL ID Act was passed. - lol

Quoting the official announcement by the Immigration & Checkpoints Authority (ICA):

No More Inked Endorsement Stamp in Passport

To realise our New Clearance  Concept (NCC) vision of automated clearance as the norm by 2023, ICA is progressively launching the electronic Visit Pass (e-Pass).

Instead of inked endorsement stamps in passports, the e-Pass is issued via an email notification to the email address declared by the foreign visitor via the electronic SG Arrival Card. It contains details of the visit pass granted, including the maximum number of day(s) of stay and the last day of stay allowed in Singapore.




Everything is digital and there's no need to.
Not going into excessive detail but over time, the plan is to go almost fully automatic, essentially using biometrics entirely. On the short term, there's almost no manned counters (and people to do the stamping), unless there's an exception. You might have to enroll the first time, but after that, its literally a self service system with no one to stamp your passport.
We're actually at a stage where some immigration processes are passport free both on land and air checkpoints. The high degree of automation both makes the need for stamping inefficient and unnecessary.

I'm not sure if its directly relevant but we also dropped physical arrival cards for digital ones tied into our covid/health reporting requirements for everyone.

Singapore wants to attract as many visitors as possible. Not stamping passports removes an obstacle for some travelers who wish to visit other countries without traces of prior trips.

In which countries would having a Singaporean stamp create an issue?

That doesn’t match reality: to enter Singapore, now you have to register online, whereas before you just walked through immigration. As a traveler, entering Singapore got more difficult, not less.

@fregante I don't think Sarah meant it is less tedious to enter Singapore, but rather that countries that might have a problem with you having visited Singapore now will not know without the stamp in your passport. That being said, I'm not aware of any countries that have a problem with having visited Singapore. More of an issue with, say, Israel, Iran, or North Korea. Israel stopped stamping passports a while back for this reason. Some majority-Muslim countries would not admit people with Israeli stamps in their passports.
